# Libgdx Statebased game not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm using Libgdx and I wanted to change the default application to a Game with multiple screens. I get an odd nullpointer that has to do with the engine. I'll show you my little setup code. Here I have the desktoplauncher:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.x = 2000;
        config.width = 640;
        config.height = 480;

        new Core().create();
    }
}
```

The core extending Game

```
public class Core extends Game {

    Play game;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        game = new Play(this);

        setScreen(game);
    }

}
```

and the Play class implementing screen:

```
public class Play implements Screen{

    Core game;


    public Play(Core game) {
        this.game = game;
    }


    public void show() {

    }


    public void render(float delta) {
        System.out.println("efsse");
    }


    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }


    public void pause() {

    }


    public void resume() {

    }


    public void hide() {

    }


    public void dispose() {

    }

}
```

It's been a bit since I've used libgdx, but tutorials showed that this is the correct format. Yet I get the exception: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at com.test.game.Core.create(Core.java:15)
    at com.test.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:13)

**UPDATE** looking at old code, the desktop launcher setup goes as following:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();

        new LwjglApplication(new Core(), config);


        config.x = 2000;
        config.width = 640;
        config.height = 480;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you need to call create() on 'new Core()' ?

Answer (score 2):

In your `DesktopLauncher` it's not enough to just new up a `LwjglApplicationConfiguration`, you have to pass that along with your `Game` instance to the constructor of a `LwjglApplication`. Try changing your `main` method to this;

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.x = 2000;
        config.width = 640;
        config.height = 480;

        new LwjglApplication(new Core(), config);
    }
}
```

The `LwjglApplication` is responsible to creating a lot of things that **libGDX** depends on, so that needs to be initialized.